# Pivot like query access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am having a huge database of records and I'm finding it to be a nightmare getting to analyse the data.

**Objective:**

Group my data by Country of Purchase (rows), by Years/Months (rows), by Product (columns) with the Sum of Paid amount being the value.

**Let me explain:**

Below is a sample excerpt from my table.

[image: MyTable]

And here is the result that I am looking for that I was able to achieve using an Excel Pivot table:

[image: MyPivot]

**Why use MS Access:**
My table has over 3 million records stored across many workbooks, and Excel has a limit of 1m in each sheet. Also Excel crashes more often than not when loading >500k of data.

I installed an older version of MS Access (2010) which has pivot tables option but it was very slow and did not allow me to group correctly. I then tried using a combination of queries and reports to arrive to my result to no avail.

Any help will be very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing the aggregation in Access and then the pivot in Excel?

```
SELECT country, year, month, product, sum(paid)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY country, year, month, product
```

(`year` and `month` based on access functions for date manipulation... alternatively, you could use is as a date to keep date functionality in the pivot - just make it the first of the relevant month)

Then use this as the source of the pivot table. The pivot table then basically just does the formatting - which it can hopefully do quickly enough